# Converting an XML file to a CSV file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, lxml, elementtree, xml.etree

I'm converting an XML file to a CSV file but having issues along the way.

I'm getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tag'.

I have done quite a bit of research into resolving this issue, unfortunately I haven't be successful in coming up with a suitable result, I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Snippet of XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filebooks xmlns="http://www.something.com/xml/xxx/filebook/2006-10-31"\>
  <filebook>
    <header filebook-id="Some Title">
      <currency>GBP</currency>
      <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Some Name</display-name>
    </header>
    <file-tables>
      <file_table product-id="111">
        <amount quantity="1">21.5000</amount>
        <file-info>xxx 01/06/2020:Test</file-info>
        <date-from>2020-06-01</date-from>
        <date-to>2020-06-02</date-to>
      </file_table>
      <file_table product-id="222">
        <amount quantity="1">18.3000</amount>
        <file-info>xxx 01/07/2020: Txt</file-info>
        <date-from>2020-07-02</date-from>
        <date-to>2020-07-02</date-to>
      </file_table>
    </file-tables>
  </filebook>
</filebooks>
```

I'm expecting an output in the CSV file in this format:

```
product_id; currency; amount; quantity; file_info; date_from; date_to
111;GBP;21.500;1;xxx 01/06/2020:Test;2020-06-01;2020-06-02
222;GBP;18.300;1;xxx 01/07/2020: Txt;2020-07-02;2020-07-02
```

This is what I've done so far.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv


tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")   
root = tree.getroot()     
ns = {'nspace': 'http://www.something.com/xml/xxx/filebook/2006-10-31'}

price_data = open('data.csv', 'w')

csvwriter = csv.writer(price_data)
price_head = []
count = 0
print (root.findall('nspace:filebook', ns)) #debugging


for member in root.findall('nspace:filebook', ns):
    price = []
    if count == 0:
        currency = member.find('nspace:currency', ns).tag
        price_head.append(currency)
        product_id = member.find('nspace:product_id').tag
        price_head.append(product_id)
        amount = member.find('nspace:amount').tag
        price_head.append(amount)
        quantity = member.find('nspace:quantity').tag
        price_head.append(quantity)
        file_info = member.find('nspace:file-info').tag
        price_head.append(file_info)
        date_from = member.find('nspace:date-from').tag
        price_head.append(date_from)
        date_to = member.find('nspace:date-to').tag
        price_head.append(date_to)

        count = count + 1

    currency = member.find('nspace:currency', ns).text
    price.append(currency)
    product_id = member.find('nspace:product_id').text
    price.append(product_id)
    amount = member.find('nspace:amount').text
    price.append(amount)
    quantity = member.find('nspace:quantity').text
    price.append(quantity)
    file_info = member.find('nspace:file-info').text
    price.append(file_info)
    date_from = member.find('nspace:date-from').text
    price.append(date_from)
    date_to = member.find('nspace:date-to').text
    price.append(date_to)

price_data.close()
```

Comment: Your xml  snippet is invalid. Please edit the question with a valid snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req
html = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<filebooks xmlns=\"http://www.something.com/xml/xxx/filebook/2006-10-31"\>
  <filebook>
    <header filebook-id="Some Title">
      <currency>GBP</currency>
      <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Some Name</display-name>
    </header>
    <file-tables>
      <file_table product-id="111">
        <amount quantity="1">21.5000</amount>
        <file-info>xxx 01/06/2020:Test</file-info>
        <date-from>2020-06-01</date-from>
        <date-to>2020-06-02</date-to>
      </file_table>
      <file_table product-id="222">
        <amount quantity="1">18.3000</amount>
        <file-info>xxx 01/07/2020: Txt</file-info>
        <date-from>2020-07-02</date-from>
        <date-to>2020-07-02</date-to>
      </file_table>
    </file-tables>
  </filebook>
</filebooks>'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
rows = []
header = ['product_id', 'currency', 'amount', 'quantity', 'file_info', 'date_from','date_to']
rows.append(header)
filebooks = doc.selects('filebook')
for filebook in filebooks:
    currency = filebook.currency.text
    file_tables = filebook.selects('file_table')
    for file_table in file_tables:
        amount = file_table.amount
        row = [
            file_table['product-id'], currency, amount.text,
            amount['quantity'],
            file_table.select('file-info>text()'),
            file_table.select('date-from>text()'),
            file_table.select('date-to>text()')
        ]
        rows.append(row)
utils.save2csv('data.csv', rows)
```

Result:

```
product_id,currency,amount,quantity,file_info,date_from,date_to
111,GBP,21.5000,1,xxx 01/06/2020:Test,2020-06-01,2020-06-02
222,GBP,18.3000,1,xxx 01/07/2020: Txt,2020-07-02,2020-07-02
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: thanks this works reading the contents hardcorded. How do I read it from a file?

Comment: @Malyk Try this: html = utils.getFileContent('sample.xml')

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, is with an xml parser, since this in xml format. This disregards the csv aspects; that obviously isn't the issue here:

```
cash = """[your xml above - validated as xml]"""
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(cash.encode())

namespaces = {'nspace': 'http://www.something.com/xml/xxx/filebook/2006-10-31'}
rows = []
for member in doc.findall('nspace:filebook',namespaces):    
    cur = member.find('.//nspace:currency',namespaces).text
    for m in member.findall('.//nspace:file_table',namespaces):
        row = []
        id = m.attrib['product-id']
        amount = m.find('./nspace:amount',namespaces).text
        file_i = m.find('./nspace:file-info',namespaces).text
        date_f = m.find('./nspace:date-from',namespaces).text
        date_t = m.find('./nspace:date-to',namespaces).text        
        row.extend([cur,id,amount,file_i,date_f,date_t])
        rows.append(row)
for r in rows:
    print(r)
```

Output:

```
['GBP', '111', '21.5000', 'xxx 01/06/2020:Test', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-02']
['GBP', '222', '18.3000', 'xxx 01/07/2020: Txt', '2020-07-02', '2020-07-02']
```

Obviously, you can reorder the fields, name headers, etc.